# AngularJS - ng-model cleaning variable when changed

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am having some trouble when making a data interpolation in AngularJS...
I created an input field for email and used ng-model to get data from this field, but when I change the text in the input field, the value in the variable is deleted ... I don't know if this makes any difference, but the data ( pages and scripts ) are coming from an Nodejs server. Here is the code:

**UPDATE**

As @devqon said, the data validation when I use email in type="email" is causing it to malfunction ... When I changed it to type="text" it worked just fine ... but, what if i want to have the input type for email???

HTML page:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <!-- JQuery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- AngularJS-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- stylesheet -->
        <link href="/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Angular Source Code -->
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <form class="form-signin">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="userEmail" required autofocus>
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        <h1>Email: {{ userEmail }} </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller('mainController',["$scope",function($scope){

    $scope.userEmail = "something";
    $scope.$watch('userEmail',function(){
        console.log("changed");
    });

}]);
```

And, if necessary, nodejs app file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');
var setupController = require('./controllers/setupController.js');
var apiController = require('./controllers/apiController.js');
var appController = require('./controllers/appController.js');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

mongoose.connect(config.getConnectionString());
apiController(app);

//appController(app);
app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));

});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: It probably is deleted because it doesn't validate to truthy. Probably because it is input type `email` but with an invalid email address. If it doesn't validate to truthy, angular doesn't apply the value to the `ng-model`

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct ... It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind the rule

> there should always be a dot in your model

Because the ngModel directive uses two way data binding. I suggest you to use the controller as syntax and update your code like

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <form class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="ctrl.userEmail" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <h1>Email: {{ userEmail }} </h1>
</body>
```

This happens because once the user changes the value, `userEmail` will be created on the child scope and the binding will use this value instead the one present int the controller. In such a way `$scope.userEmail` will remain the same as the initial value.

Comment: Where would it bind to a new child scope?? He already initializes the value in the controller, so the `ng-model` should bind correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a validation in html5 and that is causing the data to bind only when a correct email in entered... I didn't even changed the code ... I just entered a valid email address and it worked!